# Chrome extension tampering with the http header can get the image, but it can't handle the background-image

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

In development, I need to judge the color of the picture. Therefore, canvas is used, but it will face cross-domain problems when processing,

I am solving it by modifying the http header, but this method is useful for image tags, but for background-image, it will be invalid.

Do you have any good solutions?

I know that extracting the background-image url, and then creating a new image should solve this problem.

I would like to ask if there is a better and more convenient way?

In html

```html
<div id='imgwiki'>this is wrong, because use background-image</div>

<img id="imgb" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system_gm/2x/content_copy_black_24dp.png" alt="imgb"> this is always ok. because it is a img tag
```

In my content.js

```js
var img=document.getElementById("imgwiki");
img=img.computedStyleMap().get("background-image");
img.crossOrigin="Anonymous";
var canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data; //here cross-domain
```

In my background.js

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(details) {
        luoism.log({details}, details.url);
        return {responseHeaders: [...details.responseHeaders,{name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",value: "*"}]};
    },
    {urls: ['<all_urls>']},   // filters
    ['blocking','responseHeaders','extraHeaders']   // extraInfoSpec
);
```

@wOxxOm, actually this code is ok, but i want a more directly solution:

```js
        !async function getcssimage(e) {

            var stylestr=e.computedStyleMap().get('background-image').toString();

            //get url
            var url='',ur=/url\("([^)"]+)/,x=false;
            if(!ur.test(stylestr)) return false;
            url=ur.exec(stylestr);
            url=url[1];

            //deal mix http & https 
            url=luoism.config.ishttps? url.replace(/^https*/,'https'):url;

            //from background-image url to <img> tag
            function makeimg(url) {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    let img=new Image();
                    img.addEventListener("load",e => {
                        resolve(e.currentTarget);
                    });
                    img.onerror=e => {
                        let t=e.currentTarget;
                        t.onerror="";
                        t.style.display='none';
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        resolve(false);
                    };
                    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
                    img.src=url; 
                });
            }


     // deal this <img>, anything is ok
            var img=await makeimg(url);
            var canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
            luoism.log('消息begin',img.toString(),{img});
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
            var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
            return x;
        }(img);
```

Comment: You'll have to create the canvas in your background script and use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass data.

Comment: @wOxxOm but why i can deal with <img>, but can not deal with background-image?

Comment: As far as I can understand the problem is in canvas so my comment is about that.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, you are right, but my way so far so good. maybe i will use your function as more common solution. thank you.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm, I have give up my way because it is not stable, now I will try your solution.